# Prompt instead of login screen [linux mint cinnamon]

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login-screen

Long story short, I've deleted `lightdm` because of the error:

> “Failed to start light display manager.”

After I reinstalled it with `synaptic`. How to get it (or smth else) back?

What and why I have done:

Installed today fresh new linux mint cinnamon 19.3. Had a problem that after log in there was no desktop, only mouse cursor. So I rebooted the system, opened the console in the login screen (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd>) and typed `startx`. Desktop appeared, but I was not satisfied that I have to manually start it. So I found "solution", that said to use `synaptic` and reinstall `lightdm`. I did that and then I got stuck on the logo/loading screen with error:

> “Failed to start light display manager.”

I've rebooted to recovery mode, opened root console and deleted `lightdm` with `sudo apt remove lightdm`, then started the network manager and upgraded all packages.

After reboot there was no login screen, only console with:

> “Enter your login.”

Well, I logged in to my account and typed `startx`. Everything works out, but now I dont have login screen at all.

Tried to install `lightdm` with `synaptic` but got stuck on logo/loading screen once again...

The question, is there any way to install new or old login screen, so I dont have to manually type my login and startx command?

System info:

- OS1: Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon
- OS2: Windows 10
- Cinnamon Version: 4.4.8
- Linux kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic
- Processor: Intel core I7-7700HQ, 2.8Ghz
- Memmory: 7.7 Gib
- Hard Drives: 126 Gb
- Graphic Card: NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti mobile
- Disks: ssd for windows and hard drive for files and Linux

Comment: It seems that this is a compound problem. If you just installed Linux mint cinnamon, try a reinstall and with the first problem you get, seek help. If you don't want to do that, I'd say be content logging in through terminal and running `startx`.

Comment: @user96931, well I did that (I mean there was no error msg or smth, it just couldn't load the desktop for some reason) and got stuck with logo/loading screen. I dont really wont to do that again :/

Comment: Hmmm, why don't you try a different version of Linux then? I'm familiar with Debian, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Because I've already installed Mint and I'm too lazy to reinstall the system once again

Comment: Ok, here's a possible solution. Try `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` That should launch the GUI login when you boot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later. Btw, I just found out that I do have login screen, but only when I already logged in. I mean, if I hit ctrl-alt-l it will appear and lock my pc. Is it possible to use this as default login screen?

Comment: If you determine which command it is using, it may be possible to run this command as the login prompt; but doing that is beyond me.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. There's still naked tty1 after boot. Well, I'll try to reinstall the system... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I've installed another distro because I didnt found any solution for mint.</s>

Never mind! There is the solution! Here's what worked for me:

So,

1. delete all nvidia drivers, then
2. reboot with `nomodest` instead `quite splash` grub boot flag
3. log in, and install nvidia drives 430.5 via driver manager, reboot.

And that's all. **System was reinstalled without any additional software, probably it could led to the successful fix, idk.**

1. remove drivers

   ```
   sudo apt purge *nvidia*; sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt remove nvidia-*; reboot;
   ```
2. hit <kbd>e</kbd> while in grub menu: change 'quite splash' to 'nomodeset'
3. boot, log in, install drivers.

This topic could also help https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=293163

Comment: Reviewers: I think it is a possible correct self-answer, not NAA and not VLQ.